# The Series of functions in Weierstrass M test

Tags: sequences-and-series, weierstrass-approximation

I have some questions regarding the sequences of functions in the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test):

**Weierstrass M-test:**. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of real- or complex-valued functions defined on a set $A$ .....

My question is specifically regarding the $f_n(x)$ in the definition. From all the example that I have seen so far, the sequence of function is usually related by the index. For example, one of the example I seen is:

$g_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n}$

So it means $g_1(x) = \frac{x^1}{1}, g_2(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}, g_3(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}$

I am just wondering does the sequence of functions i.e. $f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x), ...$

have to be related like the above example? Or it could be like this:

$f_1(x)= \sin(x), f_2(x)=\cos(x), f_3(x)= x^2+x + 11, f_4(x)=\frac{3^x}{5}$, ...

Because when I was looking at the proof of the theorem, it seems it is using the partial sum of each of the above functions i.e. looking at $S_n(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)+f_3(x)+...+f_n(x)$

Does the $f_1(x), f_2(x),... f_n(x)$ have to be related? or they could be totally arbitary different function defined on the same domain?

Thank you

Comment: They can be arbitrary, as the theorem states.

Comment: if you look at the proof, it never assumes form of $f_n$ to be related to $n$ in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects to your question:

1. The functions $f_{n}$ in the $M$-test are assumed to satisfy
   $$
   \sup_{x \in A} |f_{n}(x)| = M_{n},\qquad
   \sum_{n} M_{n} < \infty.
   \tag{*}
   $$
   That *is* a relationship between $f_{n}$ and the index $n$, albeit one that's particularly weak. In this sense, it's inaccurate to say the $f_{n}$ are "totally arbitrary".
2. You can apply the Weierstrass $M$-test to a sequence $(f_{n})$ that starts off with the functions you mention. In order for a function sequence to be defined, however, $f_{n}$ has to be specified for all $n$. In practice, that's usually achieved by having $f_{n}(x)$ be given by a closed formula involving $n$. In this sense, you're unlikely to encounter
   $$
   \sin x + \cos x + (x^{2} + x + 11) + \tfrac{3^{x}}{5} + \cdots
   $$
   in practice, and very likely to see, e.g.,
   $$
   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!},\qquad
   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-nx},\qquad
   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^{2}}.
   $$

---

In case a bit of theory helps: Convergence of an infinite series is *entirely determined by asymptotic behavior of the tail, not by any finite number of terms*. To give a precise formulation, if $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence (of complex numbers, say), then following are equivalent:

- For *some* $N \geq 1$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges.
- For *every* $N \geq 1$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges.

Consequently, condition (*) in the $M$-test *is not a condition on any finite collection of the $f_{n}$, but a condition on the asymptotic behavior of the suprema*. You can "fold in" or remove an arbitrary finite set of terms without changing whether or not the series converges.

Or, if you like, in the Weierstrass $M$-terst, an arbitrarily long initial finite sequence of terms *is* completely arbitrary, even though the asymptotic behavior of the tail is not.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Hwang for your explanations. I think it is quite clear. But I just have one more question, since you mentioned that the M-test is more concerned about the tail behavior, does it mean we would never have something like this: $\frac{x}{x^n}$ at the end of the series of function? but it is possible to have those terms say for the first 855 terms in the series? but some other sequences of functions that would converge after the 855th functions in the sequences?  Say we can have the sequence of functions being:

Comment: $g_1(x) = \frac{x}{x^1}$, $g_2(x) = \frac{x}{x^2}$, ..., $g_{855}(x) = \frac{x}{x^{855}}$, $g_{856}(x) = \frac{x^1}{1!}$, $g_{857}(x) = \frac{x^2}{2!}$, $g_{858}(x) = \frac{x^3}{3!}$, .... as you mentioned above?  thank you

Comment: The "tail" of a series refers generically to the terms remaining after finitely many terms have been dropped, so "finitely many terms in the Weierstrass $M$-test are arbitrary" means "folding in finitely many terms has no effect on uniform convergence". On the other hand, for the $M$-test to make sense, each summand $f_{n}$ must be _bounded_. If $A$ is the real line (or the set of non-zero real numbers), a function such as $g_{2}(x) = x/x^{2}$ can't arise, since that function isn't bounded on $A$. [...]

Comment: For the functions in your second comment, you _do_ have that the sequence of partials sums starting with the $856$th partial sum (i.e., including all the singular terms) converges uniformly to the sum of the entire series. The $M$-test itself doesn't apply to the entire series, but does show the convergence$$f_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=856}^{856+n} g_{k}(x) \to \sum_{k=856}^{\infty} g_{k}(x)$$is uniform, so that$$\sum_{k=0}^{856+n} g_{k}(x) \to \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_{k}(x)$$is also uniform ("in $n$"), even though the terms of the sequence and the limit may be unbounded on $A$.

Comment: Hi Dr. Hwang, from the very last two equations here you shown, does it mean you are saying the series of functions that I used: i.e. the $g_1(x) = \frac{x}{x^1}$, $g_2(x)=\frac{x}{x^2}$, ... ,$g_{858}(x)=\frac{x^3}{3!}$, ... would still converge uniformly? And when you said "M-test itself doesn't apply to the entire series, but does show the convergence", does it mean you are saying from the 856th sequence of function onwards, partial sums converges, so we end up having the whole infinite series from k=0 to k=$\infty$ converges? i.e. we still have 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n(x) $$ converges?

Comment: where the $g_n(x)$ are the functions that I was using above? even thought the first 855 functions are unbounded say on the interval of [-1,1] if we consider the set A as the interval [-1,1]?  Sorry for my lengthly questions and comments. But I just hope to get the understanding correct. Thank you.

Comment: Recall the definition: $(f_{n}) \to f$ _uniformly on $A$_ if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $|f_{n}(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ in $A$. For partial sums, $f_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} g_{k}$, "uniform summability" (or "uniform convergence of the series") means: For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that if $n \geq N$, then$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} g_{k}(x)\right| < \epsilon\quad\text{for all $x$ in $A$.}$$The $M$-test says: If $sup_{x\in A}|g_{k}(x)| = M_{k}$ and $\sum_{k} M_{k}$ converges, the series is uniformly summable on $A$.

Comment: If finitely many of the $g_{k}$ are unbounded on $A$, then $\sum_{k} M_{k}$ doesn't make sense (some of its terms are infinite). If $f_{N_{0}}$ is a partial sum including all the unbounded terms, however, the $M$-test may still apply to the tail $(f_{n})_{n=N_{0}+1}^{\infty}$, allowing us to deduce that the entire sequence $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges uniformly on $A$. In that sense, your first comment is correct.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Hwang. I think I understand much much more and more clear in the understanding of the M-test and the general convergence of series (i.e. the focus of asymptotic behaviour). Happy New Year 2017!